# Get content from one page and show it on another page

Tags: posts, pages, content, the-content

So, I've been googling and reading and testing and failing.

I'm fairly new to php, so don't expect to much :)

I'm working on a new design, and I want to show content from the about page on my homepage, which is dynamic. So, I've been looking into that the_content thing, but I havent gotten any luck so far.

```
<?php
   $id=about;
   $post = get_page($id=);
   $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
   echo $content;
?>
```

the ID of the page is "about", if that is any help.

Please get back to me :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off: The ID of a post or page is always an integer. "about" is either your about page's title, [slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Post_Slug) or both.

Including the following in your "homepage's" [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) or in the sidebar combined with [conditional tag(s)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) will display the about page's content:

```
<?php
    // query for the about page
    $your_query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=about' );
    // "loop" through query (even though it's just one page) 
    while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
    // reset post data (important!)
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

**Edit:** The above works, IFF your page's slug is indeed "about", otherwise adjust accordingly.

Comment: This only displays the content, not the title of the page too. Yet doing things like the_title() shows the homepage title

Comment: Not if done inside the loop it won't.

Answer (score 1):

The codex is your friend!

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

```
<?php
    $post_id = 7;
    $post = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
    $title = $post['post_title'];
    $content = $post['post_content'];
?>
```

(ARRAY_A - Returns an associative array of field names to values)

It's a start.

Comment: I have been using the codex, but I find it hard to understand. Keep in mind that I've been coding php for like 2 days :)

Comment: All in fun :) - hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar but with page **Title**, this is how I achieved it:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'title' => 'The title of the page you want'
);

$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to get the current page content

```
global $post;
echo $post->post_content;
```

or

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->post->post_content;
```

Comment: The question was: how to display a different page (page `about`) content on homepage. `About` page isn't set as homepage. It was not about displaying the content of the current page.